# Bash text processing

Tags: bash, awk

I have three files: `file1`, `file2` and `exl`. Both `file1` and `file2` have *two* columns of content. The first column is the same in both files.

I want to join the content of both files using that column. That's easy using the `join` command. But there is a problem with the `exl` file: it contains some words, which I want the `join` command to ignore/delete.

Is there any way to do that with `join` or should I use `awk` instead?

file1:

```
A la  
B lb  
C lc  
D something
```

file2:

```
A ba  
B bb  
C another  
D bd
```

exl:

```
something  
nothing
```

Expected Result:

```
A la ba  
B lb bb  
C lc  
D bd
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to exclude any values in `exl` field from the join column of `file1` and `file2`? And how are columns delimited? Could you give like three sample lines from each file?

Comment: Provide example input and output in your question please.

Comment: @oguzismail edited

Comment: Why is `another` not part of the expected result? It is not present in `exl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the join, you could use sed to remove the words in exl.  The trick is to put all the excluded words into one pipe-delimited line first, which awk could help with.

```
EXCLUDE=`awk '{if(NR>1){printf("\\\|")}; printf(" %s", $1)}' exl`
join -1 1 file1 file2 | sed "s/$EXCLUDE//"
```

First, put all the excluded words into one line with awk, and assign the output to EXCLUDE (escaped-pipe delimited, which sed requires).  Then simply join and replace all the EXCLUDE words with nothing (ie. remove all words in EXCLUDE).

Could also skip the temporary variable, and do this in one line:

```
join -1 1 file1 file2 | sed "s/`awk '{if(NR>1){printf("\\\|")}; printf(" %s", $1)}' exl`//"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gjoin -t $'\t' <(gjoin -t $'\t' -v 1 file1 exl) <(gjoin -t $'\t' -v 1 file2 exl)
```

(For my setup, Mac OS X with GNU tools installed, and with tab-separated values; change for your case.)

The `<(...)` construct sets the output of a command as a virtual file that the outer command line can accept as a parameter.

The `-v 1` parameter to `join` means: "print all lines of the first file that are unjoinable".

Thus, `gjoin -t $'\t' -v 1 file1 exl` will try to join the first file with the exclusion list, and only print those that are not on the exclusion list. Similarly for `file2`.

Then we take the output of those two negative joins into the real join.

Comment: Didn't work for me in linux, tried with join instead of gjoin and nothing